# How to `executeScript` before page load by WebDriver in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to use webdriver in nodejs to control a website which use ajax very heavy, especially it always have http request to server.

When I use `driver.executeScript` , I found the promise returned almost never resovled.

I checked the website, found that it use a `keep-alive` http request loop to communicate with server. That means, it will always have at least one live connection to server for 30s, then another connection for another 30s, again and again. which cause `document.readyState` keep `interactive` instead of `completed`, and then `driver.executeScript` almost be blocked forever.

I had tried `driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT_MS)` but it only throws a exception after timeout.

I also tried to stop the connections by press ESC on the browser window. after that, it seems `driver.executeScript` can run immediately. But I didn't find any function like `window.stop()` in WebDriver API.

so is there have a way to resolve this problem? Either should be ok like:

1. run `executeScript` right now, ***regardless*** of whether page is loaded;
2. a webdriver api like `driver.browser.stop()` could stop all live connections in page.

Nodejs code to re-produce this problem:

```
const WebDriver = require('selenium-webdriver')

const driver = new WebDriver.Builder()
.withCapabilities(
  WebDriver.Capabilities.firefox()
  .set('webdriver.load.strategy', 'unstable')
).build()

driver.get('https://wx.qq.com/')

driver.executeScript('return "99% will be blocked, 1% luck to return"')
.then(function (ret) {console.log(ret)})
```

thanks!

> UPDATE:
>   I found maybe set `webdriver.load.strategy` to `unstable` in firefox will be help.
>
> `FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
>   fp.setPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable"); WebDriver
>   driver = new FirefoxDriver(fp);`
>
> https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4993
>   https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#page-load-strategies-1

Links from others got same problem:
http://grokbase.com/t/gg/webdriver/1263dbyws6/how-to-click-stop-button-or-equivalent

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you don't use Implicit time the driver won't wait till it's loaded so you'll be able to execute your script.

If this don't work you can try to use your own timer. Check if doc state is ready, if it's not ready after some timeout then stop it manually (by JS) and run your script.

Comment: ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState == 'complete'"); it's C#.
And do this Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)); before.

Comment: I tried but it's not work. (I use nodejs) `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0)` did not help, the `executeScript` is still blocked. How to use my own timer? and I can't execute any JS code now because of this "blocking".

Comment: I found maybe it's related to `document.readyState`. because it seems WebDriver only execute script when `readyState=="completed"`, but in this case, readyState stay on `interactive` ...

Answer (score -3):

By using `Thread.sleep(secs);`. For example, we want to load a page in 3 secs means we write `thread.sleep(30000);`.

Comment: That will wait for 30 seconds not 3. Also this will just lock the execution of the code so it will do nothing for 30 seconds.